# Oracle vs MySQL - Insert

Tags: mysql, oracle, insert

In Oracle, the below statement works perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO fake_table (names, gender)
     VALUES ( (SELECT distinct(name)
                 FROM target_table),
             'F');
```

I don't want to touch the `SELECT` statement - `SELECT distinct(name) FROM target_table`

Being said that, I want same fucntionality in MySQL. I got many codes with Static values within Select statement, but I am not looking for that.
**Simply put; I am looking to initialize 'F' separatly.**

Thank you for your help in advance. :)

Comment: tl;dr `rownum` is Oracle specific functionality. You're going to have to change it... sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008539/limit-results-in-mysql (for example)

Comment: Thx for the quick reply @Ben... however I am not interested in rownum alternative. I am looking to initialize 'F' apart from Select statement. Pardon me if my question was not straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO fake_table (names, gender)
  SELECT s.*, 'F'
    FROM (
      -- your query
      SELECT distinct(name) FROM target_table
    ) s
```