# Mysql limit on left join results

Tags: mysql, geolocation

I am trying to find our nearby branches that can serve a list of our customers (company_id) locations. The two tables (customers 'locations' and our 'branches') both have indexed lat / lng fields. This MySQL query works using the haversine formula and returns all branches within 25 miles of each location.

```
select locations.id,locations.street, locations.city, locations.state,branches.id, branchname,branches.city,branches.state,
(3956 * acos(cos(radians(locations.lat)) 
                     * cos(radians(branches.lat)) 
                     * cos(radians(branches.lng) 
                     - radians(locations.lng)) 
                     + sin(radians(locations.lat)) 
                     * sin(radians(branches.lat)))) as branchdistance
from locations
left join branches on 
                   (3956 * acos(cos(radians(locations.lat)) 
                     * cos(radians(branches.lat)) 
                     * cos(radians(branches.lng) 
                     - radians(locations.lng)) 
                     + sin(radians(locations.lat)) 
                     * sin(radians(branches.lat)))) < 25
where locations.company_id = 388
order by locations.id, branchdistance
```

However I want to limit the number of branches (left join) returned to a max of 5. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `order by locations.id, branchdistance LIMIT 5` Not work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIMIT results in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008539/limit-results-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks @MTK .. but that only limits the whole query of locations. We want to limit the resulting matched elements of the left join.  Adding to the last statement simply limits the number of locations returned not the number of branches per location.  We want all locations and the top 5 (max) that are within 25 miles of each location.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally after a lot of hair pulling I found the answer:

```
select 
a.id,
b.id,
st_distance_sphere(a.position, b.position)  * 0.00062137119 dist
from addresses a
inner join branches b
on b.id = (
    select b1.id
    from branches b1
    where st_distance_sphere(a.position, b1.position)  * 0.00062137119  < 25
    order by st_distance_sphere(a.position, b1.position) 
    limit 1
)
```

By way of explanation we are trying to allocate thousands of leads (addresses) to the closest of many hundreds of branches each of which have a service radius of 25 miles.

Each table (addresses & branches) have lat, lng and a geospatial position column.

I modified the original query to use MySQL 5.7 geospatial functions (st_distance_sphere) but the Haversine formula would still work.

Hope this is of value to someone.